# Linux Wi-Fi disconnects instantly?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

I've gotten NetworkManager installed on Arch, and it seemed to be working. But all of a sudden, when I boot, the Wi-Fi connects for all of 5 seconds, then stops working, then NetworkManager says it's disconnected. It will refuse to connect until I reboot, and when I reboot it will automatically connect, then die after 5-10 seconds again. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems on Arch linux, and its always (for me) ended up being one of two things:

1.) I had the wrong security/credentials setup for the network I was trying to connect to. For some reason, a lot of the indicators show you as "connected" when the status is actually just authenticating.

2.) I had more than one wireless manager running (e.g. networkmanager AND netctl or wicd). To fix this, use systemctl to remove the conflicting tool. This is easiest to accomplish by doing `systemctl disable [tab][tab]` and removing the conflicting entries it lists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem many years ago. The better solution for me was to install wicd and remove NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue (or at least something very similar) on my laptop (running Slackware64 14.2), where on one specific wireless network (broadcast by a Charter/Spectrum-provided wireless router) NetworkManager would successfully connect for a whole second, then immediately disconnect.  Other networks (including my phone's hotspot) worked fine, and my phone worked fine on the same network.

Decided to do a `tail -f /var/log/messages` and noticed a message about DHCP failing to get an IPv6 address.  Disabled IPv6 in NetworkManager for the 5GHz network (i.e. change "IPv6 Configuration" from "Automatic" to "Ignore") and it now it works like a charm.

So yeah.  Try disabling IPv6 and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with a D-link usb wi-fi. In my case the problem was that the driver was not included in kernel and I had to add the driver myself